# Not sure if a comma is needed?

Tags: grammar, commas, prepositional-phrases

The program is designed for multi-generations of guests with no previous experience to easily and safely explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) on an expertly guided tour

The program is designed for multi-generations of guests with no previous experience**,** to easily and safely explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) on an expertly guided tour

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by experience. Do you mean to say _people without experience in exploring the sea floor_?

Comment: Side note: "Multi-generations" is not correct and should be replaced by "multiple generations" (if I'm understanding your intended meaning).

Answer (score 2):

One way to break up this rather over-long sentence is to use *paired* commas to make the phrase *with no previous experience* parenthetical. You would do this like this:

> The program is designed for multi-generations of guests, with no previous experience, to easily and safely explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) on an expertly guided tour.

However I would prefer to break up the sentence a little, perhaps like this:

> The program is designed for multiple generations of guests with no previous experience: it will provide them with the opportunity to explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) safely on an expertly guided tour.

Although my sentence is a little longer it better separates the descrition of the target group from the description of the tour. As both of those are complex concepts it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in meaning.
With the comma it means that "In order to easily and safely explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) on an expertly guided tour, the program is designed for multi-generations of guests with no previous experience." (Here it doesn't seem practical that this would be the intended meaning, but sometimes the alternative is equally viable.)

Without comma, it means what I think you want to say: that it helps people with no previous experience safely explore the sea floor.

Answer (score -1):

The program is designed for multi-generations of guests with no previous experience [of diving] to easily and, safely explore the sea floor (or an aquarium) on an expertly guided tour.